# jQuery editable/non-editable form

Tags: jquery, forms

I want to make my form editable when I click the edit anchor tag, once the form is posted it will reload the page. The form should be then just viewable (with label tags), not editable. When I click edit anchor tag again, it should be editable (the input element will be converted into label).

What I want is to convert the input tags into labels, with the same value.

I have an div which is used as a navigation bar

```
<div id="nav". <a href="">edit</a> </div>
```

My form

```
<form id="profile-form" action="save.php">
<input type=text id="name" name="name">
<input type=text id="email" name="email">
</form>
```

I tried bit of jquery but it didnt work.

```
('#edit').click(function) { $('#profile-form').html(<label><?php $_POST['name']?></label>)
 )};
```

Comment: You need to put your html in quotes, and you also have a typo ('labe' instead of 'label'). So in full: `$('#profile-form').html("<label><?php $_GET['val1']?></label>")` (assuming this is php preprocessed).

Answer (score 0):

Well there are some typos, that may lead to incorrect results

```
<div id="nav">
```

Also you are trying to access an element with id=edit, none exists.
I am guessing
    edit

```
$('#edit').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

This would be the correct set of statements. Your jQuery construct is syntactically not right.

Comment: is it possible to change the input element, i dont want to change the whole form html. Just want to change all the input elements into labels...

Comment: You can set the property of the input elements as `disabled`. This is like <input type=... name="name" disabled>. Thats it. That disables the box for any input